# How to render a specific contents in a html page based on User Role using Flask-User

Tags: python, flask

I have developed an application using flask and also used Flask-User to implement role based authorization to specific routes using '@roles_required' decorator in routes module for specific views to render html pages.

Now, I have a situation where in I need to render the same template for a specific view however certain information like 'service cost' on the template be displayed only to specific role.

Is there an elegant way to achieve this in Flask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use current_user attribute in jinja template to only render a specific part if current user has the required role like this:

```
{% if current_user.has_role('<enter role here>')
```

Comment: Thanks @gittert, that worked for me. Only had to use 'has_roles' instead